# LaTeXML and pdfpages

Tags: pdf, conversion, pdfpages, html

I can't find a lot of informations about LaTeXML here but I hope somebody can help me.

In a LaTeX document, I use a `\includepdf` with the option `pages`. I have created a mystyle.sty.ltxml in which I use the following macro :

```
RequirePackage('graphics');
DefMacro('\includepdf[]{}','\includegraphics[#1]{#2}');
```

When I want to compile with :

```
latexmlpost --dest=mypage.xhtml mydoc.xml, latexmlpost
```

the script transforms my pdf to a png. But every page is print above the previous, so we can't read the file. (by example, [this png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YA4pu.png) was generated from a "3 pages document")

Does someone have a solution ?

Sorry for my bad english

Answer (score 1):

The best place for asking LaTeXML questions is probably the LaTeXML mailing list (http://lists.jacobs-university.de/mailman/listinfo/project-latexml). There is also a bug tracker at https://trac.mathweb.org/LaTeXML/ if you think your question is more a bug.

The two main developers of LaTeXML are present (and active) the list and TRAC.